Why is Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation.Revit nuget package for version 2025 is incorrectly packaged?
msbuild results in compilation errors due to missing namespace and types when using Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation.Revit 2025 nuget package.
Previous versions (2024, 2023...) compile successfully. Comparing the contents of 2025 and 2024 nuget packages, there are some discrepancies which could be the culprit of failed compilation.

A new version of the 'Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation.Revit' NuGet package, version '2025.0.1', has been released.
We kindly request that you consider updating your NuGet package to the latest version.
